# Change E-mail used in VS Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, if the sign-in e-mail is changed for a user what will happen? Will work history be retained under the new e-mail address?

Edit: To hopefully clarify, the sign-in email is not the owner of the VSTS account. This is tied to a user who is just a stakeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [change account owner for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs), this operation won't affect any history.

If you want to use a different e-mail that no relationship with previous account, that means you need to sign up a new account, then everything will be fresh.

Comment: Thanks, Cece, but in this case the user is not the account owner, but rather a stakeholder.

Comment: So you just want to add users and assign stakeholder access to Visual Studio Team Services, correct? As a stakeholder, you can access the backlog, task and Kanban boards, and work items. Of course you can see the work items history.

Comment: No, I'm asking If a user's sign-in e-mail for VSTS is changed or they want to use a different e-mail, would the system treat them as a new user?

Comment: Yes. That means you sign up a new account, everything will be fresh.

Comment: Ok. That's what I needed to know. If you make that the answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Yes, I have modified the answer.